# jeditable expand submitdata

Tags: javascript, jeditable

The following example is given on the jeditable site:

```
$(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php";, {
   submitdata : function(value, settings) {
       return {foo: "bar"};
   }
});
```

I'd like to know how to format in order to return multiple hashes. Something like the following:

```
$(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php";, {
   submitdata : function(value, settings) {
       return {foo: "bar", foo2: "bar2"};
   }
});
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".editable").editable("http://www.example.com/save.php", {
    submitdata: function (value, settings) {
        return {
            foo: "bar",
            foo2: "bar2"
        };
    }
});
```